# Default value when no checkboxes selected

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails form for creating users with a hidden field:

```
= hidden_field_tag "user[site_ids][]", @current_site.id, :data => @current_site.id, :class => 'current_site_id'
```

which sets the site_id of the current_site.

I also have a few checkboxes that have all the sites listed:

```
- Site.all.each do |site|
  %label.checkbox
    = check_box_tag 'user[site_ids][]', site.id, false, :class => "sites_checkbox"
    = site.name
```

The reason I have the hidden field is si if the user doesn't select any of the checkboxes that it will at least set the `@current_site`.

I was thinking of using JQuery like this: if the user selects one of the checkboxes that I set the value to 999 which is not in the db:

```
$(".roles_selected").click(function() {
  var selected = $(this).closest("label");
  if (selected.attr("data") == 'superadmin') {
    $('.current_site_id').val(999);
  } else {
    $('.current_site_id').val($('.current_site_id').attr('data'));
  }
});
```

and in the controller maybe removing 999 from `params[:user][:site_ids]`

That seems so hackish... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 5):

A more straightforward solution would be to set the default site in the create/update methods of your controller.  For example, something like:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
@user.sites << @current_site if params[:user][:site_ids].empty?
```

Then you can get rid of the hidden field in your form and the jquery.

Comment: and maybe move this to the model (with a after callback, or using a custom creator, there are many options)